# How to check access to a given ressource with Asp.Net Core Identity attributes

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, authorization, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

We are currently architecturing our next application. For each deployment, we will have different "organizational" level:
[image]

We will have several endpoints, either to read either to edit data for each division/factory. The idea is to assign a user with a permission to any level of this tree:

- UserA can be Reader of Division 1 and Admin of Division 2(which would
  cascade the rights to their factory)
- UserB could be just reader of Factory 3
- UserC could be reader of the Root-organization(which will cascade) but admin of factory 3

Now, let's admit we are trying to read/write

```
GET : http://service-url/api/factories/4
--> UserA/UserC should be allowed but not UserB POST: http://service-url/api/factories/4
--> UserA/UserC should be allowed but not UserB

GET : http://service-url/api/factories/3
--> UserA/UserB/UserC should be allowed POST: http://service-url/api/factories/3
--> UserA/UserC should be allowed but not UserB
```

I've started to check how to do this, I've seen that I can add additional claims in my token. I could even compute every inherited rights at the creation of the token and having something like:

```
new Claim("roles", "division2:admin,factory3:read")
```

I've then searched how I can validate that the current user has the rights to execute the service URL, but the closest thing I could find was to do a policy:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(authOpt =>{
  authOpt.AddPolicy("IsRessourceAdmin", policyBuilder =>{
    policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    policyBuilder.requireClaim("roles", ...);
  }
});
```

but:

1. I don't think I've access to the ":id" currently being modified
2. I'm not sure we can do "contains" or custom logic to validate the claim?

So it possible to validate my scenario? It feels kind of a standard scenario, where the role is assigned to a given ressource for a given user, but I can't find a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is not to use roles, and instead use claims as a way to determine authorization.

Basically, you could have that a user have the following claims:

```
Divisions: [division1]
Factories: ["factory1:read", "factory2:readwrite"]
```

Do check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t34Cff0pBmA&ab_channel=NDCConferences

To implement the above, do check out the policy concept in ASP.NET Core
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0

With requirements, your architecture looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. That would imply knowing the full list of factories/division at build time(and having all my customer with the same structure). Those organization data/levels) are something the user will create and will be stored in the database. Also, the endpoint will be the same, just with a different provided id. I don't see how a static policy could do the trick here?

Comment: see the concept of Requirements here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0#requirements , that allows you to do lookups if needed during authorization. Policies with claims gives you a much better flexibility in your authorization than using roles.

Comment: I'm checking the "PermissionHandler" of your link, but what would be the `object? ressource` when having an API call?  Also, while checking your "Policy-based authorization", I just found about the "resource-based authorization", when would you use one or the other?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked that much with resource authoriztation, so I have no experience there. But we have many ways to achieve authorization. With policy and requirements you can get a very nice auth architecture.

Comment: just saw this link today https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/advanced-techniques-around-asp-net-core-users-and-their-claims

Comment: I thank you for your answers, but as of today, I still don't see how I can retrieve the id of my route, and once I've my ID, I'm not sure either on how to get the data from the user. Also, since we will have differents permissions, it mean that we would end with a giant HandleAsync method that has all the knowledge for each permission)

Comment: Authorization is hard and someone needs to "own" the responsibility to decide who can access what. Either you create a dedicated authorization service, that can look that up on the fly. There are products to help you doing this, like https://solliance.net/products/policyserver

Comment: but, also, as my picture shows, you can have multiple handers, each one "voting" on the user and who is in charge of checking the different levels, perhaps one hander for factory access and one hander for the division access.

Comment: Yes, I've understand this. It's how to technically validate the rest that I'm not sure?

Comment: I guess creating a service, that is responsible for authorization is one approach and that you can reuse for other services as well.  Or you let your token provider to decide that during login and just add a claim for each division and factory that each user has access to? So that makes the clients and APIs much easier.. Just let each client/API listen for a 
 specific claim.

Comment: yeah, but how in the classes that you propose, do I get the ID of the factory/Division/organization that I'm trying to access? How do I retrieve the claim of the current users?

Comment: All you need to do is to in IdentityServer ,connect it to its database and have it being populated with each users claims. So when he authenticates, you lookup the users claims in the database and then pass those claims in the access token, then the API's just needs to look for the correct claim that it requires to authorize the user. You do not need to do the actual lookup in the APIs, just let the API's listen for access tokens with the correct claims (like Factory3:read-write), that's it. The database model for IdentityServer, uses the ASP.NET Identity tables.

Comment: you're not listening. If my controller `GetSomeData(int factoryId)` get called with the ID 3, how would the identity framework know that this should be translated as a `Factory3:read` claim? Not to mention, if I access to something else, like:  `GetMachine(int idMachine)`, for which you should retrieve the machine to check in which factory it is located in order to know it should be this `Factory3:read` claim ?

Comment: Hi, I missread your question, but I agree that your approach with new Claim("roles", "division2:admin,factory3:read") is good and your machines knows in what factory/division they belong to and based on that config, it knows what claims to look for, so Machine3 when it receives an access token, it will look if the claim Machine3 (divisionX or factory:X) and you can do that using the authOpt.AddPolicy..

Comment: I'm sorry, but at this point, it seems I'm just going to repeat myself. This still does not explain, how, from a controller method:  `public async Task<ActionResult<MachineDto>> Get(int machineId)`, I could implement something that get the machine Id, retrieve the Machine, determine that it's related to   `Factory3:read` claim, and then have the identity framework checking if my current user has this claim. It's business knowledge, I've no choice but to write some code for it, and I don't see how I can achieve this inside an  `AuthorizationHandler` or a  `Policy`

Comment: The authorization/policies is handles before the request even reaches the controllers, so its like a gatekeeper that only will allow the incoming request to reach the controller. The JwtBearer handler will convert the incoming access token into a ClaimsPrincipal user and then its up to the authorization hander to determine if the user contains the desired claims or not.  each API that receives should be configured to look for different tokens.